# Rename UPLOADS folder with custom WP_CONTENT_DIR

Tags: customization, uploads, directory

For version control purpose, our client has a WordPress app with directory structure like this:

```
.
|_____app
|  |_____themes
|  |_____plugins
|  |_____uploads
|_____index.php
|_____WordPress
|_____wp-config.php
```

In `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', __DIR__ . '/app');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', WP_HOME . '/app');
```

Now, she want to rename all default WordPress folders in app directory.

With `plugins` and `themes` we can do it easily by using `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` and [register_theme_directory()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_theme_directory/). But, somehow, it's not easy to rename `uploads` folder.

I have tried many modifications with `UPLOADS` constant, but it can't help because custom uploads folder is always created inside `WordPress` directory.

Are there any ways to workaround this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging around, I ended up with using [`upload_dir`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_dir/) filter.

Here is what I tried in `functions.php` to change `uploads` to `media`. Hope it can help someone too :)

```
 add_filter('upload_dir', function($uploads)
 {
     $custom = [];

     foreach ($uploads as $key => $value) {
         if ( false !== strpos($value, '/app/uploads') ) {
             $custom[$key] = str_replace('/app/uploads', '/app/media', $value);
         } else {
             $custom[$key] = $value;
         }
     }

     return $custom;
 });
```

Many thanks to [@gmazzap](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/35541/gmazzap) for the guidelines and the suggestion about `upload_dir` filter!

Comment: +1 but a note, I hate partial matching as it may end in unexpected results (what about the site everybodecandouploads ? ;) ) so I would say that to be safe it is better be more specific with the replacing even if it is longer code, for example replace `site_url(/wp-content/uploads)` with `site_url(/wp-content/media)`

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the source of [`_wp_upload_dir`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_upload_dir/), you'll see:

```
if (defined('UPLOADS') && ! (is_multisite() && get_site_option('ms_files_rewriting'))) {
    $dir = ABSPATH.UPLOADS;
    $url = trailingslashit($siteurl).UPLOADS;
}
```

So `UPLOADS` can only be used to define a foder relative to `ABSPATH`, which I guess is `/WordPress` folder in your setup.

In the same function, you can see that if `get_option('upload_path')` and `get_option('upload_url_path')` are empty, the path and the URL of uploads folder are set to, respectively, `WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/uploads'` and `WP_CONTENT_URL.'/uploads'` which should be perfectly fine for you, as long as you define `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and `WP_CONTENT_URL` like in OP.

If you don't define `UPLOADS`at all and the uploads folder is still not resolved to `/app/uploads`, very likely your database contains *some* value for `'upload_path'` and `'upload_url_path'` options.

You have 2 possibilities:

- delete those options
- use [`"pre_option_{$option}"`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_option_option/) filters to force `get_option()` to return something empty for those options (but not `false` or the filters will be ignored).

For the second possibility the code could be something like this:

```
add_filter('pre_option_upload_path', '__return_empty_string');
add_filter('pre_option_upload_url_path', '__return_empty_string');
```

With the above code in place, and without any `UPLOADS` constant defined, as long as you define `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and `WP_CONTENT_URL`, the uploads folder should be resolved correctly.

If that not happen, there must be something that acts on *some* filter, for instance [`upload_dir`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_dir/).

Comment: Thanks you! If i don't define `UPLOADS`, `app/uploads` is created normally as long as i defined `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and `WP_CONTENT_URL`. `upload_path` and `upload_url_path` are empty strings in database by default and there're no modifications using `upload_dir` filter. But I still unable to rename `app/uploads` to something like `app/custom`.